# Grouping events in R that occur withing a given time frame/period

Tags: r, time-series, timespan

I am currently using R. I have a large table of data with an hourly time stamp, and an observation for each hour.  I need to group all observations > 0 that occur within 4 hours of each other as a single event.  Example data is below:

```
Date            Obs
2017-12-01 5    0.01
2017-12-01 6    0.5
2017-12-01 7    0.2
2017-12-01 8    0
2017-12-01 9    0.03
2017-12-01 10   0.01
2017-12-01 11   0
2017-12-01 12   0
2017-12-01 13   0
2017-12-01 14   0
2017-12-01 15   0
2017-12-01 16   0
2017-12-01 17   0
2017-12-01 18   1.2
2017-12-01 19   0.6
```

For instance the first six rows would be a single event (0.01, 0.5, 0.2, 0. 0.03, 0.01), since there is only one hour of a non observation (a zero).  Then the consecutive rows of 4 zeros or more would trigger a non-event. Event 2 would be started next time we have a positive reading (1.2, 0.6) etc.

I have attempted to do this using the rle() function.  For example:

```
events <- rle(data$Obs > 0)
```

However, this creates a non-event for every 0. Is there a simple solution to this?  Thanks.

Comment: Can groups extend indefinitely if observations continue happening unabated? Said another way, would it accomplish what you want by splitting things up at points where there are 4 consecutive "0" observations? If not, you might be looking to do some kind of rolling window function?

Comment: I'd say separate events by >0 and 0 in obs field. Then use data.table() as from this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212530/identify-a-value-changes-date-and-summarize-the-data-with-sum-and-diff-in-r) which may help you in this case.

Comment: @lemonC Thanks for the link and suggestions, I did not consider data.table(), and I think the link has some useful info I can use with this project in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using data.table notation, using run lengths to determine if a region is long enough to split groups:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(120)

# Toy data set
dat <- data.table(time=seq(1,1000), obs=sample(c(0,0.01, 0.1, 1), size=1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1)))

# calculate run lengths for the observation values
o <- rle(dat$obs)

# assign a new column assigning each row(timepoint/observation) its run length
dat[, length := unlist(lapply(o$lengths, function(x) rep(x, each=x)))]

# determine if the region should be considered an "interruption"
dat[, interrupt := ifelse(obs==0 & length>= 4, TRUE, FALSE)]

# assign values to each alternating interruption/grouped region
dat[, group := rleid(interrupt)]

# Remove sections with >= 4 obsevations of 0
dat2 <- dat[interrupt==FALSE]

# Re-number groups starting at 1
dat2[,group := as.numeric(as.factor(group))]
```

which should give you what you're looking for

```
time  obs length interrupt group
   1 0.00      2     FALSE     1
   2 0.00      2     FALSE     1
   3 0.01      1     FALSE     1
   4 1.00      1     FALSE     1
   5 0.01      1     FALSE     1

 992 0.10      1     FALSE     6
 993 0.00      1     FALSE     6
 994 0.01      1     FALSE     6
 995 0.00      1     FALSE     6
 996 0.10      1     FALSE     6
```

At that point, you can follow-up with whatever you want to do with your groups. For example calculating mean by group,

```
dat2[, list("average"=mean(obs)), by=group]
```

yields

```
group   average
    1 0.1391803
    2 0.1415838
    3 0.2582716
    4 0.1353086
    5 0.1011765
    6 0.1896774
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  This seems to do exactly what I need, much appreciated!