# Temporally correlating events with date ranges

Tags: r, date, time-series, grouping, correlation

I have a dataframe of extreme temperature events in R. The data looks something like this:

```
data <- data.frame(date_start = c("1980-05-11", "1980-07-12", "1980-08-17", "1980-05-10", "1980-05-23"), date_end = c("1980-06-27", "1980-07-29", "1980-09-03", "1980-05-19", "1980-06-27"), lat = (c(31, 31, 31, 32, 32)), lon = c(-119, -119, -119, -120, -120)) # Create dummy data
data$date_start <- as.Date(data$date_start) ; data$date_end <- as.Date(data$date_end)

data
#  date_start   date_end lat  lon
# 1 1980-05-11 1980-06-27  31 -119
# 2 1980-07-12 1980-07-29  31 -119
# 3 1980-08-17 1980-09-03  31 -119
# 4 1980-05-10 1980-05-19  32 -120
# 5 1980-05-23 1980-06-27  32 -120
```

I want to correlate events with overlapping time windows (i.e. the events in the 1st and 4th rows). The goal is to understand the spatial extent of each event (how many lat/lon values does it extend over).

Given date_start and date_end values, what is the best way to group my dataset into events which occurred concurrently?

I have tried looping through every day of interest and extracting the events for that day, but then I have to correlate my events across dates. This method is also very inefficient.

I think there could be some useful content in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258808/grouping-events-in-r-that-occur-withing-a-given-time-frame-period), but this doesn't quite get me where I need to be since my events have a date *range* rather than a single date per event.

Any thoughts would be deeply appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution would be to use the [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/) package, which was specifically created for working with interval data like this.

```r
library(ivs)

data <- data.frame(date_start = c("1980-05-11", "1980-07-12", "1980-08-17", "1980-05-10", "1980-05-23"), date_end = c("1980-06-27", "1980-07-29", "1980-09-03", "1980-05-19", "1980-06-27"), lat = (c(31, 31, 31, 32, 32)), lon = c(-119, -119, -119, -120, -120)) # Create dummy data
data$date_start <- as.Date(data$date_start)
data$date_end <- as.Date(data$date_end)

# Merge [start, end) into an interval object
data$range <- iv(data$date_start, data$date_end)
data$date_start <- NULL
data$date_end <- NULL

# Identify the interval "group" that each row falls in
data$group <- iv_identify_group(data$range)

# Optionally, turn that into an integer id for grouping
# (but you could also group on `group`)
data$id <- vctrs::vec_group_id(data$group)

data
#>   lat  lon                    range                    group id
#> 1  31 -119 [1980-05-11, 1980-06-27) [1980-05-10, 1980-06-27)  1
#> 2  31 -119 [1980-07-12, 1980-07-29) [1980-07-12, 1980-07-29)  2
#> 3  31 -119 [1980-08-17, 1980-09-03) [1980-08-17, 1980-09-03)  3
#> 4  32 -120 [1980-05-10, 1980-05-19) [1980-05-10, 1980-06-27)  1
#> 5  32 -120 [1980-05-23, 1980-06-27) [1980-05-10, 1980-06-27)  1
```

Comment: Apologies for not seeing this earlier--this is great and also completely solves my question!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach with `data.table`. You can `order` your data by start and end dates, then assign increasing group numbers when the start date exceeds the running maximum end date. This will group rows 1, 4, 5 that have overlapping date ranges into a single group (1).

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)
data[order(date_start, date_end), group := cumsum(date_start > shift(cummax(as.integer(date_end)), fill = 0))]
data
```

**Output**

```
   date_start   date_end lat  lon group
1: 1980-05-11 1980-06-27  31 -119     1
2: 1980-07-12 1980-07-29  31 -119     2
3: 1980-08-17 1980-09-03  31 -119     3
4: 1980-05-10 1980-05-19  32 -120     1
5: 1980-05-23 1980-06-27  32 -120     1
```

Comment: This is incredibly useful, thank you so much @Ben. It worked almost perfectly, except for one group it made with slightly overlapping dates. This group included four different date frames (May, June, July, and August in 1980) and I can't figure out why. The end dates didn't overlap with the start dates... any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: @KailaFrazer Glad to hear it was helpful. It's hard to tell from the description what's going on. If you're able to reproduce the problem, you can edit your original post/question and describe it further (perhaps with example data to demonstrate). One thought is that you can have a number of date ranges all linked together - all it takes is one large overlapping range, and it will group all small ranges that overlap with it in a single group.