# Efficiently find the first of the last 1's sequence

Tags: r, vector, sequence, run-length-encoding

I have the following vectors with 0s and 1s:

```
test1 <- c(rep(0,20),rep(1,5),rep(0,10),rep(1,15)) 

test1
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
                                                                          ^
test2 <- c(rep(0,8),rep(1,4),rep(0,5),rep(1,5),rep(0,6),rep(1,10),rep(0,2)) 

test2
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
                                                            ^
```

I need to find the index of first 1 in the last sequence of 1s (indicated by ^ in the above code). I have a solution (below) that doesn't perform well, how could I improve the performance?

For `test1` and `test2`, the **expected output** is 36 and 29, respectively.

Here is a sub-optimal solution:

```
temp1 <- cumsum(test1)
which(temp1==max(temp1[duplicated(temp1)&temp1!=max(temp1)]+1))[1]
[1] 36

temp2 <- cumsum(test2)
which(temp2==max(temp2[duplicated(temp2)&temp2!=max(temp2)]+1))[1]
[1] 29
```

Note: The length of actual vectors is ~10k.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another way with `which` + `diff`.

```r
idx <- which(test1 == 1)
idx[tail(which(c(0, diff(idx)) != 1), 1)]
#[1] 36
```

Comment: This will fail in case there is only one `1` sequence. Try it with `test1 <- c(0,1,1,0)` where I would expect `2` as a result but here I get `integer(0)`.

Answer (score 19):

The `data.table` library has a non-exported function called `data.table:::uniqlist(list(x))`. Use three colons `:::` to access non-exported functions. This function determines when columns of a data.frame change value and return indices of the change.

```
data.table:::uniqlist(list(test1))
# [1]  1 21 26 36
```

@Arun talks about `uniqlist` here:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/21267854/10276092

Then I use the `y[length(y)]` method of finding the last item in a vector, and base `ifelse()` to check if the last index contains a 1, else the second to last index must contain a 1.

```
fx <- function(x) {
    y <- data.table:::uniqlist(list(x))
    ifelse(x[y[length(y)]] == 1, y[length(y)], y[length(y) - 1])
}
```

Comment: `uniqlist` is so efficient, which is far out of my expectation, +1!

Answer (score 18):

Using *rle*:

```
r <- rle(test1)
ix <- max(which(r$values == 1))
sum(r$lengths[ 1:(ix - 1) ]) + 1
# [1] 36

r <- rle(test2)
ix <- max(which(r$values == 1))
sum(r$lengths[ 1:(ix - 1) ]) + 1
# [1] 29
```

Comment: I'm `rle`'s biggest fan :-) .   So much so that I wrote `seqle` , a function which finds sequence lengths where you can specify the increment.

Answer (score 16):

Run rle and then use cumsum to calculate the end positions of each run and subtract the lengths and add 1 to get the start positions and then reduce that to the runs of 1's only and finally take the last element.  This gives the start position of the last run of 1's but if you wanted:

- the end position just omit the `-lengths+1`
- the last run of 0's replace the `==1` with `==0`
- the first run of 1's replace `tail` with `head`

If there are no 1's it returns a zero length numeric vector.

```
with(rle(test1), tail((cumsum(lengths) - lengths + 1)[values == 1], 1))
```

Answer (score 14):

For completeness, here is the benchmark with a vector of size 30001. Feel free to update this if needed.

```
x <- c(rep(0,14736),rep(1,413),rep(0,830),rep(1,961),rep(0,274),rep(1,12787))


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(rle_zx8754(x),
                               rle_Grothendieck(x),
                               which_diff_Maël(x),
                               uniqlist_Viking(x),
                               while_Ritchie(x),
                               #Position_Ritchie(x),
                               #detect_index_Ritchie(x),
                               diff_Thomas(x),
                               #regex_Thomas(x),
                               #regexpr_Thomas(x),
                               times = 1000, check='equal')



Unit: microseconds
                 expr   min     lq      mean median     uq
        rle_zx8754(x) 339.5 350.45  783.9827 357.45 375.15
  rle_Grothendieck(x) 352.7 364.75  616.2324 372.60 391.75
   which_diff_Maël(x) 264.2 274.60  404.5521 279.50 292.00
   uniqlist_Viking(x)  16.7  22.30   32.1502  25.40  30.65
     while_Ritchie(x) 777.6 785.60 1021.0738 801.95 847.15
       diff_Thomas(x) 279.4 286.90  500.6373 291.20 306.35
      max neval  cld
 156630.3  1000   cd
  11196.5  1000  bc 
   7263.2  1000  b  
   3524.9  1000 a   
   6739.7  1000    d
   9435.5  1000  b
```

functions:

```
x <- c(rep(0,14736),rep(1,413),rep(0,830),rep(1,961),rep(0,274),rep(1,12787))


rle_zx8754 <- function(x){
  r <- rle(x)
  ix <- max(which(r$values == 1))
  sum(r$lengths[ 1:(ix - 1) ]) + 1
}

which_diff_Maël <- function(x){
  idx <- which(x == 1)
  idx[tail(which(diff(idx) != 1), 1) + 1]
}

rle_Grothendieck <- function(x){
  with(rle(x), tail((cumsum(lengths) - lengths + 1)[values == 1], 1))
}

uniqlist_Viking <- function(x){
  y <- data.table:::uniqlist(list(x))
  ifelse(x[y[length(y)]] == 1, y[length(y)], y[length(y) - 1])
}

while_Ritchie <- function(x){
  l <- length(x)
  while (x[l] - x[l - 1] != 1) {
    l <- l - 1
  }
  l
}
Position_Ritchie <- function(x){
  Position(isTRUE, diff(x) == 1, right = TRUE) + 1
}

detect_index_Ritchie <- function(x){
  purrr::detect_index(diff(x) == 1, isTRUE, .dir = "backward") + 1
}

diff_Thomas <- function(x){
  max((2:length(x))[diff(x) == 1])
}

regex_Thomas <- function(x){
  nchar(sub("(.*01).*", "\\1", paste0(x, collapse = "")))
}

regexpr_Thomas <- function(x){
  attr(regexpr(".*(?<=0)1", paste0(x,collapse = ""), perl = TRUE), "match.length")
}
```

Answer (score 12):

A simple `while` loop will be a (potentially very) fast approach where the sought index is towards the end of the vector.

```
f <- function(x) {
  l <- length(x)
  while (x[l] - x[l - 1] != 1) {
    l <- l - 1
  }
  l
}

f(test1)
[1] 36
f(test2)
[1] 29
```

We could also use `Position()` or the `purrr` equivalent `detect_index()`:

```
Position(isTRUE, diff(test1) == 1, right = TRUE) + 1
[1] 36
purrr::detect_index(diff(test1) == 1, isTRUE, .dir = "backward") + 1
[1] 36
```

Comment: I feel like this would be an obvious approach in most other languages, but in R it's really thinking outside the box. Love it.

Comment: Yes. Why waste time looking at the start of the vector?

Answer (score 9):

I believe you have many ways to do it, and below are some possible approaches:

---

- ## `regex` approaches

You can try `regex`, like `sub` + `nchar`

```
f1 <- function(v) nchar(sub("(.*01).*", "\\1", paste0(v, collapse = "")))
```

or `regexpr`

```
f2 <- function(v) attr(regexpr(".*(?<=0)1", paste0(v,collapse = ""), perl = TRUE), "match.length")
```

- ## `diff` approaches

Or, some other `diff` options, like

```
f3 <- function(v) tail(which(diff(v) == 1) + 1, 1)
```

and

```
f4 <- function(v) max((2:length(v))[diff(v) == 1])
```

Answer (score 9):

Another way using `rev` and `match`.
`rev` reverses the vector, so that `match`, which returns the first hit, can be used to find the last 1 sequence.

```
f <- \(x) {
  . <- rev(x)
  i <- match(1, .)
  if(is.na(i)) return(NA)
  j <- match(0, tail(., -i))
  if(is.na(j)) 1
  else length(.) - i - j + 2 }

f(test1)
#[1] 36
f(test2)
#[1] 29
f(c(1,1))
#[1] 1
f(c(0,1))
#[1] 2
f(c(1,0))
#[1] 1
f(c(0,0))
#[1] NA
```

Or write a function using `Rcpp` doing the same but can iterate starting from the end.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("int f2(NumericVector x) {
  auto i = x.end();
  while(i != x.begin() && *(--i) != 1.) ;
  while(i != x.begin() && *(--i) == 1.) ;
  if(*i != 1.) ++i;
  return i == x.end() || *i != 1. ? 0 : i - x.begin() + 1;
}")

f2(test1)
#[1] 36
f2(test2)
#[1] 29
f2(c(1,1))
#[1] 1
f2(c(0,1))
#[1] 2
f2(c(1,0))
#[1] 1
f2(c(0,0))
#[1] 0
```

Or using `rev`, `diff` and `match`.

```
f3 <- \(x) {
    i <- match(-1, diff(rev(x)))
    if(is.finite(i)) length(x) - i + 1
    else if(x[1] == 1) 1
    else NA
} 

f3(test1)
#[1] 36
f3(test2)
#[1] 29
f3(c(1,1))
#[1] 1
f3(c(0,1))
#[1] 2
f3(c(1,0))
#[1] 1
f3(c(0,0))
#[1] NA
```

---

Benchmark

```
uniqlist <- function(x) {  #M.Viking
  y <- data.table:::uniqlist(list(x))
  ifelse(x[y[length(y)]] == 1, y[length(y)], y[length(y) - 1]) }

which_diff <- function(x) {  #Maël
  idx <- which(x == 1)
  idx[tail(which(c(0, diff(idx)) != 1), 1)] }
```

```
# Dataset from question
x <- rep(c(0,1,0,1,0,1), c(14736,413,830,961,274,12787))
bench::mark(max_iterations = 1e5, f(x), f3(x), which_diff(x),
 uniqlist(x),  f2(x) )
#  expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 f(x)          199.07µs  251.5µs     3412.    1.21MB    76.3   1341    30
#2 f3(x)         218.05µs 319.61µs     3144.    1.76MB   117.    1079    40
#3 which_diff(x) 155.01µs 177.53µs     5518.  954.17KB   103.    2296    43
#4 uniqlist(x)    17.04µs  17.72µs    55386.    1.36MB     4.04 27442     2
#5 f2(x)           5.61µs   6.13µs   161213.    2.49KB     6.16 78462     3

# Data with many changes between 0 and 1 and hit at end
x <- rep(c(0,1), 1e6)
bench::mark(max_iterations = 1e5, f(x), f3(x), which_diff(x),
 uniqlist(x),  f2(x) )
#  expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`  n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>  <int> <dbl>
#1 f(x)           17.97ms  19.86ms      44.6   76.29MB     50.5     23    26
#2 f3(x)          28.77ms  32.78ms      25.6  114.44MB     52.9     14    29
#3 which_diff(x)  14.47ms  16.91ms      52.3   68.67MB     67.8     27    35
#4 uniqlist(x)     2.66ms      3ms     294.     7.63MB     27.8    148    14
#5 f2(x)           1.08µs   1.28µs  701103.     2.49KB     21.0 100000     3

# Data where hit is at beginning
x <- c(0,1,rep(0, 1e6))
bench::mark(max_iterations = 1e5, f(x), f3(x), which_diff(x),
 uniqlist(x),  f2(x) )
#  expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 f(x)            4.34ms    6.6ms     131.    19.11MB     84.6    71    46
#2 f3(x)           15.1ms  18.73ms      35.9   57.24MB     75.7    18    38
#3 which_diff(x)   1.37ms   1.44ms     529.     7.63MB     93.9   265    47
#4 uniqlist(x)   470.91µs 491.54µs    1994.     1.36MB      0     997     0
#5 f2(x)         364.46µs 375.08µs    2649.     2.49KB      0    1325     0

# Data where hit is at end
x <- c(rep(0, 1e6),1,0)
bench::mark(max_iterations = 1e5, f(x), f3(x), which_diff(x),
 uniqlist(x),  f2(x) )
#  expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`  n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>  <int> <dbl>
#1 f(x)           10.53ms  11.33ms      69.8   38.18MB     91.8     35    46
#2 f3(x)          14.19ms  17.18ms      37.6   57.24MB     69.3     19    35
#3 which_diff(x)   1.38ms   1.49ms     512.     7.63MB     77.9    256    39
#4 uniqlist(x)   479.76µs 491.61µs    1997.     1.36MB      0      999     0
#5 f2(x)           1.08µs   1.28µs  683440.     2.49KB     27.3 100000     4
```

The Rcpp function is the fastest and allocates the lowest amount of memory. Its performance depends where the match could be found.

Comment: the Rcpp is always the winner, +1! One more comment, searching from the tail suits for the specially when knowing that `1`'s appear in latter part of the sequence. From the time complexity perspective, the worst case for the `rev` approach (or similar alternatives) is having `1`s only at the beginning of the sequence.

Comment: But how would I know, when starting from the beginning, that there is no `0 1` somewhere in the end? When starting from the end I know, that this is the last and don't need to go to the values until the beginning. But yes `rev` is already going over all values. I don't know a function like `match` going from back to front and allows starting from a specific index, so I wrote it in C++.

Comment: yes, we don't have prior info how `0` and `1` are distributed in the sequence. My point was that, if we start from the tail, it would be less performant on `c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0)` than `c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1)`, just for example.

Comment: I don't see any way to improve this. When starting from the beginning then the needed time will not be affected by the arrangement of the data. But then I have to go to every vector content. So starting from the beginning will be only in case the match is at the beginning equal performant but in all other cases it will *less performant* than starting from the end. And yes, the provided data will affect the time taken during the benchmark.

Comment: No worries, I was just talking about the worst case, but it's a good thing in your answer that you take advantages of some useful features from the sequence.

Answer (score 4):

May not be the best but just an alternate for easy understanding

```r
data.frame(var1=c(rep(0,20),rep(1,5),rep(0,10),rep(1,15))) %>% 
  mutate(new=rleid(var1), row=row_number()) %>% 
  filter(var1==1 & max(new)==new) %>% 
  slice_head(n=1) %>% 
  select(row)

# output

  row
1  36
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also use `rleid` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

i1 <- rleid(test1)
min(which(i1 == max(i1[test1 == 1])))
# [1] 36
i1 <- rleid(test2)
min(which(i1 == max(i1[test2 == 1])))
# [1] 29
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table::rleidv()`

```
rle_seq <- data.table::rleidv(test2)
rle_ones <- rle_seq[test2 != 0]
which_id_last <- rle_ones[length(rle_ones)]
which(rle_seq == which_id_last)[1L]
[1] 30001
```